# Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result'

Tags: c#, .net, task

So i'm trying to learn how to program with Task's and i'm doing an exercise:

```
public static int ReturnFirstResult(Func<int>[] funcs)
{
        Task[] tasks = new Task[funcs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < funcs.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = CreatingTask(funcs[i]);
        }
        return Task<int>.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks, (firstTask) =>
                                                            {
                                                                Console.WriteLine(firstTask.Result);
                                                                return ***????***;
                                                            }).***Result***;
}
private static Task CreatingTask(Func<int> func)
{
        return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return func.Invoke(); });
}
```

I'm giving a array of Funcs to run, the ideia is to returns the result of the first that func that was done.
The problem is that the field Result is not available...

What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're returning `Task` from the `CreatingTask` method - you need to return `Task<int>`, and then change `tasks` to be `Task<int>[]` instead of `Task[]`.

Basically, `Task` represents a task which doesn't produce a result - whereas `Task<T>` represents a task producing a result of type `T`. In your case, everything throughout your code returns `int`, so you need `Task<int>` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you Jon, now i got it :)

Comment: Oh.. So having just a Task is more like void, so obviously we can't have void.result (kind of), but with Task<int> we now are getting some value thus we can get the Result. Thanks Jon :)

Answer (score 6):

You will get this error if you're trying to use `.Result` on a `Task` object. This might be because you meant to use `Task<T>`. But, if you want meant to use Task and you want it to return without using await then Task is like void and does not have a result. You can use `.Wait()` instead. This returns void.