# Why can't use Task<>.Result property?

Tags: c#, task

I have a problem with my tasks. When I try to recive returned variable from my task I can't use a .Result property to get it. Here is my code:

```
var nextElement = dir.GetValue(i++).ToString();
Task buffering = Task<byte[]>.Run(() => imageHashing(nextElement));
bitmapBuffer = buffering.Result;
```

and imageHasing function is declared like this:`public bool[] imageHashing(string path)`

I get an error saing:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no
>   extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Example from [this microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7) works, and I can't understand why.

Comment: Well, good news, because your use of Task here is completely pointless.  You're blocking the current thread, so you can just call imageHashing directly and skip Task.Run.

Comment: You need to declare it as `Task<byte[]>`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333297/threading-tasks-task-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-result) for explanation.

Comment: Or use var instead

Comment: I mean it's not totally pointless, it's adding the aditional overhead of spawning a thread pool thread and then using that, so it is making your code **a lot** less efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, the compiler error is in your variable declaration (`Task` does not have a `Result` property):

```
var nextElement = dir.GetValue(i++).ToString();
var buffering = Task.Run(() => imageHashing(nextElement));
bitmapBuffer = buffering.Result;
```

However, this code is also problematic. In particular, it makes no sense to kick work off to a background thread if you're just going to block the current thread until it completes. You may as well just call the method directly:

```
var nextElement = dir.GetValue(i++).ToString();
bitmapBuffer = imageHashing(nextElement);
```

Or, if you are on a UI thread and do not want to block the UI, then use `await` instead of `Result`:

```
var nextElement = dir.GetValue(i++).ToString();
bitmapBuffer = await Task.Run(() => imageHashing(nextElement));
```

Answer (score -2):

You should declare buffering variable as  `Task<byte[]> buffering = Task<byte[]>.Run(() => imageHashing(nextElement));`

Answer (score -3):

You should use `Task<bool[]>` for the buffering variable. Not specifying the type means that the operation is not expected to return any result.